# l3coffins -- Wrong width if the coffin contents is a list

Tags: lists, expl3

In the example below you see that the `coffin` with the input `enumerate` has the wrong with. I can fix this by using `\@parboxrestore`.

1. Is there an expl3-solution?
2. Should this solution be the default for coffins?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document} 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\coffin_new:N \l_xframed_store_one_coffin 

\NewDocumentEnvironment { xframed } { }
 {
  \vcoffin_set:Nnw \l_xframed_store_one_coffin { .7\linewidth }
 }
 {
  \vcoffin_set_end:
  \fboxsep0pt\fbox{\coffin_display_handles:Nn \l_xframed_store_one_coffin { red }}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{xframed}
\kant[2]
\end{xframed}


\begin{xframed}
\begin{enumerate}
\item foo
\item bar \verb+1+
\end{enumerate}
\end{xframed}

\makeatletter
\begin{xframed}
\@parboxrestore
\begin{enumerate}
\item foo
\item bar \verb+1+
\end{enumerate}
\end{xframed}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fix does not actually need all of `\@parboxreset`: a simple

```
\linewidth\hsize
```

will do it. Probably we need to alter this in `l3coffins` as unless the LaTeX3 `l3galley` module is loaded then there is nothing to alter `\linewidth` in the coffin code.

Comment: Indeed! `l3galley` does it. In this case I must use it.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel My point is that `l3galley` can't really be loaded with 'unmodified' LaTeX2e files, but `l3coffins` can. So we should make sure that the coffins code covers this case in package mode.

Comment: I noticed this. If `l3galley` is loaded, I can't work with `\linewidth`.

Comment: I've updated the SVN to fix this: will be in the next CTAN snapshot in June.